# Where is the key to the guarded door?

Tags: dark-souls-3

So there's a locked door in the Tower on the Wall location that I can't find the key to. Whenever you go down the stairs and past the three hooded undead guys, you go down a ladder (or hole in the floor) and there's a guy with a halberd in that room. After killing him, you come across an iron bar door. It's locked, obviously. I've looked all over the wall, the Undead Settlement, and even the Road of Sacrifices. I sadly haven't gotten past there yet. Anyway, I was wondering if anyone could please explain to me how to get the key to that door. If you could tell me thank you so much.

[image]

EDIT: I'll try to be more specific. First, you start at the bonfire on the location called the Tower on the Wall in the High wall of Lothric level. You go down the stone stairs and when you look straight ahead, you will see a red Lothric Knight exiting through a door, and a hooded Hollow on the other side of the room. You kill the hollow, and go down the wooden stairs on his side. On the floor that those stairs lead to, there are two more hooded Hollows. You kill them and on the floor of that same room is a hole with a ladder leading down. Go down that ladder and there will be a tall Hollow with a Halberd. Once you kill him, in that SAME room, there is a door that is made of iron bars. It's locked. I need to know where the key is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the key from [Leonhard](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Leonhard) after completing the first two steps of his quest:

> 1. **Start**: You will first meet Leonhard after reaching the second bonfire at the High Wall of Lothric. Return to Firelink Shrine to find
>      Leonhard leaning against Holy King Lothric's throne. Speaking to him
>      will grant you five Cracked Red Eye Orbs.
> 2. After obtaining 1 Pale Tongue, and lighting the Cliff Underside bonfire or defeating the Curse-Rotted Greatwood in the Undead
>      Settlement, Leonhard will give you the Lift Chamber Key to the locked
>      door below the Tower on the Wall bonfire. (Note: Pale Tongue must
>      still be in the inventory at this encounter, if you use it, he will
>      not appear)

Comment: Thanks Jutschge. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is the door which can be opened with [Cell Key](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Cell+Key). It's located on lower floor of so called workshop - big house not far from Tower bonfire, on it's roof you can see multiple hollows worshipping tree - go to the right, use ladder, then enter the building. There will be Knight with spear and shield, after beating him continue to lower floor it has anvil and is guarded by multiple hollows and two hounds - second hound is located downstairs just next to Cell Key.

If my description is not clear, just check [this walkthrough video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y4B8RXe2wY)

Comment: No I already got the cell, I tried looking it up on google before I posted the question and it mentioned something about the 'grand library'? I would post a picture to make the question more clear but it won't load. Sorry for the misconception.

Comment: @KerikoKraft it would be great if you add picture

Comment: It won't put the picture on. Would it help if I tried to explain it with more detail?

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, this is the Lift Chamber Key - not the Cell Key. The main difference is the Lift Chamber is *in the room* with the Undead Halberd wielder, and you can only see the lift behind the door. The Cell requires you to pass through this room, and two more (containing more enemies), until you can clearly see Greirat in the Cell.